# How to use constants with string interpolation in Angular routes declaration?

Tags: angular, typescript, import, circular-dependency

Route segments have been moved to constant. The code below is simplified, but in project about 5 lazy modules, each have about 20 routes, and segments often used in services and components for `router.navigate` and as string keys in objects (f.e. image for some components: `assets/images/${urlSegment}.jpg`).

For this reason segments have been moved to constants.

**routing.module.ts**

```
export const PATIENT_URL_SEGMENTS = {
  TOOLS: 'tools',
  INDEX: 'index',
}; 

const routes = [
{ path: PATIENT_URL_SEGMENTS.TOOLS, component: ToolsComponent }
{ path: `${PATIENT_URL_SEGMENTS.TOOLS}/:${PATIENT_URL_SEGMENTS.INDEX}`, component: ToolDetailsComponent }]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class PatientRoutingModule { }
```

`RoutingModule` is used in lazy loaded module. If I import `URL_SEGMENTS` from a separate file, in browser console I see the error:

> `Can not read split of undefined`

But if a constant is declared in place as in the example above, all is ok.

There is one small problem, circular dependency warnings:

[image]

One warning for each component that imports `PATIENT_URL_SEGMENTS`, because at the same time these components have been imported in the routing module. In fact there is no error, but I'd like to remove warnings for cases when components import `PATIENT_URL_SEGMENTS`.

Do you know how to achieve this? Maybe it is possible to move constant declarations to a separate file?

Comment: How is that more readable or maintainable than `{ path: 'tools/:index', component: ToolDetailsComponent }`? You're just obfuscating your code, IMHO.

Comment: @JBNizet In mose cases, you are right, but there are lot of components and services, that use this segments for `router.navigate`, also there are lot of cases when segments used as string keys. I've simplified the code in the example, but actually there about 20 routes in this module and about 5 modules. And sometimes other module need this segments too. When you have about 100 routes it is handy to have them in constants.

Comment: In general, I would agree: DRY, etc. But in this case, you and your coworkers will probably read the code of this file, and the code of the templates containing links, and the code of the components using router.navigate() hundreds of time, and will pay the readability price every single time. And all that only to facilitate the very unlikely case where you would decide to change the path of the route or the name of the parameter.

Comment: @JBNizet I think that all depends on the project. We usually write: `PATIENT_URL_SEGMENTS. ` than ctrl + space and select the variant. It was very annoying jump to other places to remeber all routes. Often this segments used as keys(most of app stored in database, without url segments wee need to support custom keys).

Comment: We have the same issue with resolvers, where we have the same resolvers used for multiple routes and we don't want to accidentally add one resolver to one route without adding it to the other. So we have a const array of resolvers and then destructure the array when defining the route's resolvers, but at runtime after a full build the resolvers are not included.